# How to delete first word from a field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table where i want to delete the first word of a filed.

For example table have a column "product name". which contains values -

```
Dabur Honey
haldiram Namkeen
Colgate Toothpaste etc.
```

I want to delete Dabur, haldiram, Colgate and make it.

```
Honey
Namkeen
Toothpaste
```

is that possible to do this using mysql query? How can i do that?

Devesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will be

```
UPDATE t SET product_name=SUBSTRING(product_name, LOCATE(' ', product_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ', -1) FROM table
```

It'll take everything after last space.

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(`product name`, instr(`product name`, ' ')) as new_prod_name
from your_table
```

or if you like to update the table

```
update your_table
set `product name` = substring(`product name`, instr(`product name`, ' '))
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/22547)